# How do I get the value of a specific field in an HTML table

Tags: html, dom, html-table, field, swig-template

I'm building a table using swig.js to step through a MongoDB document and want to allow the user to delete an entry from the table which will then be removed from Mongo. Unfortunately, when I get it to return the id of the record to be deleted, my function always returns the value in the first line.

Each line has a delete button and the relevant record id. How do I get the value of the record id for line that the button's on?

Here's my code:

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="text-center">
          <h1>Story Details</h1>
      </div>
      <div>
          <br />
          <div class="container">
              <div class="col-md-12 column list-group">
                  {% for story in stories %}
                  <div class="list-group-item">
                      <table id="table" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
                          <tbody>
                          <tr><td> <button onclick = deleteStory(document.getElementById("rec").innerText)>Delete</button></td>
                              <td><strong>Title:</strong> {{ story.title }}</td>
                              <td><strong>&nbsp&nbsp&nbspGenre:</strong> {{ story.genre }}</td>
                              <td><strong>&nbsp&nbsp&nbspWord Count:</strong>{{ story.length }}</td>
                              <td><strong>&nbsp&nbsp&nbspRecord created:</strong> {{ story.createdOn.toDateString() }}</td>
                              <td id="rec", name="rec">{{story.id}}</td>
                          </tr>
                          <tr>
                              <td colspan="6">
                                  <strong>Notes/Comments:</strong> {{ story.notes }}
                              </td>
                          </tr>
                          </tbody>
                      </table>
                  </div>
                  {% endfor %}
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div><!-- /.container -->
  <script>
      function deleteStory(id) {
          console.log(id);
      }
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What about `<button value="{{ story.id }}">`? Also, your HTML is wrong: an ID has to be unique, and you are setting the same ID for that `<td>` multiple times.

Comment: That's worked perfectly. Thanks.